# Python matplotlib produces empty subplot when trying to make 4 subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (40, 40)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)

axs[0, 0].plot(xcoords, ycoords)
axs[0, 1].scatter(xcoords,ycoords,s=1)

axs[1, 0].bar(xcoords, ycoords)
axs[1, 1].bar(ycoords, xcoords)

plt.show()
```

First 3 graphs get created as expected, but the fourth one is just blank
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Aeh.png)

Any help appriciated

Comment: Without seeing the data, it is hard guessing. But note that `plt.locator_params()` only acts upon `axs[1,1]` as that is the current ax.

Comment: @JohanC I'm not sure why you repeat my answer in your comment. But more so, your comment is not entirely correct: the default width is 0.8 (as per the documentation), not 1. And using width=10000 makes a *single* bar so wide that the bars will easily overlap, making the figure hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The default width of a bar for `matplotlib.pyplot.bar()` is 0.8](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html). That is usually fine, but if your x-axis runs from 0 to 110.000 or so, that is tiny. So tiny, that Matplotlib will not draw the bars, or more likely, they will not be rendered (and even if they were rendered, you wouldn't be able to see them).

So the data is there, just "invisible".

Increase the bar width. For example:

```
axs[1, 1].bar(ycoords, xcoords, width=100)
```